# How to get element from angular model?

Tags: angularjs

So, I have e.g. this controller:

```
angular.module('example', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = '' // Here, I want to know the element this property is binded to..
});
```

and the following markup:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
  ...

  <input type="text" ng-model="data" required>

  ...
</div>
```

Now how do I get the input-element inside controller by the bind? In other words, how do I get the element binded on `$scope.data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better question is what are you trying to do?  In angular a single element on your scope could be binded to multiple html elements through a variety of mechanisms so trying to find everything it influences is very difficult.  On the upside, it's probably not necessary.

One of the major tenants of angular is that you should update your model and let your view take care of itself, that is, it's okay for the view to be dependent on the model, but the model **should not** be dependent on the view.